# Image button in html

Tags: html

I'm trying to get a button that has an image on it. I've seen stuff like the following but they don't give you the button press/release effect that a normal button does.

```
<input type="image"  id="saveform" src="logg.png " alt="Submit Form" />
```

Is there a way to get the button click/release effect but just slap an image inside the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is, by applying a `background-image` to the `button` like so:

HTML

```
<button>Click Me</button>
```

CSS

```
button{
  background-image: url("YourImageHere");
  color: #FFF; //random values
  height: 50px; //random values
  width: 100px; //random values   
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pmje8903/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.yourButton{
    background:url("logg.png") no-repeat;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:40px;
    height:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with the input button you can try this code:

```
<input type="image"  id="saveform" src="logg.png " alt="Submit Form" />
```

and your css will look like this:

```
#saveform {
    outline: none; //To remove the blue outline ( the blue line ) when the focus event occurs
}
#saveform:active {
    transform: scale(0.9,0.9);
}
```

However if you do not want to try the with the input tag, you can use this code:

```
Html:

<button id="saveform"  type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>

CSS:

#saveform{
  background-image: url("SourceOfYourImage");
  height: 50px; // Any value
  width: 100px; //  Any value
}
```